# Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reducers

I'm trying to connect `Redux`, but I have the following error.I am new in `react native` please solve issue. please tell me how to use `Redux`to edit my code.

> Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Detailsscreen)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(DetailsScreen) in connect options.

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import FirstPage from './pages/FirstPage';
import SecondPage from './pages/SecondPage';
import ThirdPage from './pages/ThirdPage';
import Conatctas from './pages/Conatctas';
import Aboutas from './pages/Aboutas';
import DetailsScreen from './pages/DetailsScreen';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const NavigationDrawerStructure = (props) => {
  const toogleDrawer = () => {
    props.NavigationProps.toogleDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toogleDrawer()}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/drawerWhite.png',
          }}
        // style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};


function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} /> */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
function firstScreenStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="firstPage">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="First Page"
        component={FirstPage}
        options={{
          title: 'First Page', //Set Header Title
          headerLeft: () => (
            <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function secondScreenStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SecondPage"
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SecondPage"
        component={SecondPage}
        options={{
          title: 'Second Page', //Set Header Title
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ThirdPage"
        component={ThirdPage}
        options={{
          title: 'Third Page', //Set Header Title
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
export default App;
```

> Detailscreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addPlace } from '../actions/place';

class DetailsScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    placeName: '',
    places: []
  }

  placeSubmitHandler = () => {
    if (this.state.placeName.trim() === '') {
      return;
    }
    this.props.add(this.state.placeName);
  }

  placeNameChangeHandler = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: value
    });
  }

  placesOutput = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList style={styles.listContainer}
        data={this.props.places}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={info => (
          <ListItem
            placeName={info.item.value}
          />
        )}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Seach Places"
            style={styles.placeInput}
            value={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}
          ></TextInput>
          <Button title='Add'
            style={styles.placeButton}
            onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
          {this.placesOutput()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 30,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%'
  },
  placeInput: {
    width: '70%'
  },
  placeButton: {
    width: '30%'
  },
  listContainer: {
    width: '100%'
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    places: state.places.places
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    add: (name) => {
      dispatch(addPlace(name))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DetailsScreen)
```

> index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './reducers/store';
import DetailsScreen from './pages/DetailsScreen';

const store = configureStore()

const RNRedux = () => (
  <Provider store = { store }>
    <DetailsScreen />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

> Store.js

```
// store.js

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import placeReducer from '../reducers/placeReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  places: placeReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer);
}

export default configureStore;
```

> placeReducer

```
import { ADD_PLACE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  placeName: '',
  places: []
};

const placeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_PLACE:
      return {
        ...state,
        places: state.places.concat({
          key: Math.random(),
          value: action.payload
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default placeReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be just a typo?

```
import DetailsScreen from './pages/DetailsScreen';
```

You name your file Detailscreen.js, the import line is written with lower and uppercase „s“

Comment: Could you try change ```AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);``` to  ```AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => <RNRedux/>); ```